# Maven spring-boot:run goal : Simplify the command line

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I need to simplify an ugly and no elegant command line:

```
mvn -pl rep-digital-api spring-boot:run -Dspring.application.json='{ "server.port": 8081, "spring": { "datasource": { "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/frontoffice", "username": "frontoffice", "password": "password", "driverClassName": "org.postgresql.Driver" }, "redis": { "host": "localhost", "port": 6379 } }, "api.url-oauth": "http://localhost:8081/oauth/token", "url-ui": "http://localhost:3000", "document.upload-dir":"/home/jcabre/data/upload", "document.pending-key":"server3-pending" }'
```

As you can figure out what I only need is to send configuration on `spring.application.json` config parameter.

I don't whether using property files could be a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use `alias` if running on Linux. I forget what the Windows equivalent was, but I'm fairly certain there was one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a profiles in your `pom.xml` for this and use `properties-maven-plugin`, but you'd need a default one with no changes and this one.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>deflt</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <activeprofile>deflt</activeprofile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <activeprofile>local</activeprofile>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>local-run</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <properties>
                                    <spring.application.json>{ "server.port": 8081, "spring": { "datasource": { "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/frontoffice", "username": "frontoffice", "password": "password", "driverClassName": "org.postgresql.Driver" }, "redis": { "host": "localhost", "port": 6379 } }, "api.url-oauth": "http://localhost:8081/oauth/token", "url-ui": "http://localhost:3000", "document.upload-dir":"/home/jcabre/data/upload", "document.pending-key":"server3-pending" }</spring.application.json>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then your command line becomes `mvn -pl rep-digital-api spring-boot:run -P local`

I use a similar set-up, but a different plugin is invoked. I might not have set the configuration correctly in this code sample.

Comment: Turns out you don't need the `activeprofile` property I'm setting. That's just something we print in a properties file using `maven-antrun-plugin` and `echo` tasks to know at runtime whether to use minified JS/css urls or not. Also the `execution` might require a `<phase>initialize</phase>`.

Answer (score 1):

You use a [externalized configuration of Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) way that has as source an environment variable **or** a system property :

> Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an
>   environment variable or system property).

So as alternative you could wrap the command in a bash/sh script that values the env variable and run spring boot but that is not really more readable :

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON = '{ "server.port": 8081, "spring": { "datasource": { "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/frontoffice", "username": "frontoffice", "password": "password", "driverClassName": "org.postgresql.Driver" }, "redis": { "host": "localhost", "port": 6379 } }, "api.url-oauth": "http://localhost:8081/oauth/token", "url-ui": "http://localhost:3000", "document.upload-dir":"/home/jcabre/data/upload", "document.pending-key":"server3-pending" }'        
mvn -pl rep-digital-api spring-boot:run
```

As other alternative with JSON Inline, you can also supply the JSON as a JNDI variable, as follows: `java:comp/env/spring.application.json.` but using JDNI for that seems a little complicated and not visible enough.

In fact you are valuing many properties. So using an externalized configuration file seems better to read/update them. 
I advise you to define them in a properties or a YAML external file :

```
mvn -pl rep-digital-api spring-boot:run 
-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=-spring.config.location=classpath:/foo.properties
```

or use `spring.config.additional-location` to add and not override the default locations (from Spring Boot 2) :

```
mvn -pl rep-digital-api spring-boot:run 
-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.additional-location=classpath:/foo.properties
```

Comment: Could it be possible to make reference to a local file instead of a classpath located file? I mean, guess I have a file on `./foo.proerties`.

Comment: Sure. If the properties is at the location where the app is started `-spring.config.location=foo.properties` should be enough.